# Makefile Fatal error: can't create obj/calc.o

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a makefile for a simple calculator for a college project. I need it done, and I've searched the web for tutorials and I eventually found this code:

```
IDIR =include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR=lib
SDIR=src

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = calc.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = calc.o libcalc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

calc: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

The output of the make command is

```
gcc -c -o obj/calc.o calc.c -I../include
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/calc.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/calc.o] Error 1
```

My professor gave us no lead nor instruction to this, so I'm really lost.

My project is divided in three folders: `lib`, `src` and `include`. `src` contains the source for the project, named `calc.c`, `include` contains the header named `calc.h`, and `lib` contains the library named `libcalc.c`.

EDIT: I figured out this error, and it was that the `obj` directory under `src` wasn't created. However, it's still not working. The new error message is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/libcalc.o', needed by `calc'.  Stop.
```

EDIT 2: I just moved the libcalc.c from lib to obj and it worked fine. Not ideal, but it does what I need.

Comment: could you `tree` your file structure and show us your tool chain? it seems your makefile runs under `src`, which i think it's supposed to run under your project root.

Comment: My guess is that you have not created the `obj` directory.

Comment: The tutorial I was following [link](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) says that it should be located under src. About the project tree, I don't know if you're talking about something specific but I failed miserably in trying to represent the tree structure of my project. (root contains (src wich contains 'calc.c' and makefile) (include wich contains calc.h) (lib wich contains 'libcalc.c'))

Comment: @AlanAu I already tried it, but it didn't work :c

Comment: Where in the source tree did you create the `obj` directory? Your makefile is in `src` so your obj directory needs to be in `src/obj`.

Comment: @AlanAu just did it, thanks. Now it's returning another error: `make: *** No rule to make target `obj/libcalc.o', needed by `calc'.  Stop.`

Comment: "the lib contains the header, named calc.h" Do you mean the include/ directory?

Comment: It's still not working because you told `make` to expect `libcalc.o` to be in `obj` but it isn't in `obj` — it should be in `lib`.  Fix your rules to tell the truth to `make`.  Fibbing is a bad idea; computers take their revenge by refusing to understand what you really want.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and how do I do that, please? :c

Comment: Remove `libcalc.o` from `_OBJ`; create a new set of macros to deal with the library code.  (Are you meant to create a library from it, or is it OK to use just an object file?)  You'll need to make sure you chase it all through carefully; it will add a fair few lines to the `makefile`, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As I said on a comment down below, there are no straight forward tutorials that teaches how to create a makefile, and I'm overburdened with finals and projects, so I really don't have time to surf google after detailed stuff on this. Can you be a little more straightforward?

Comment: OK — I'm burdened with work and life and such like too, and don't have the time to look for tutorials, etc. You need to learn how to adapt existing code. You need macros and rules like the `OBJ` series that work with the library code instead. They'll have different names, of course. You'll list the library macro after the `$(OBJ)` macro in the link dependencies and in the link commands. You need to think clearly if you're going to pass finals. You can start by thinking clearly about how to replicate code cleanly. Don't make pathetic excuses on SO; it doesn't win sympathy. We've been there too.

Comment: i doubt your new code up there would work. `makefile` picks the first rule to work with as default, if not specified. and the rest are the same as Jonathan stated. you as a student should learn how to learn, and how to learn things by yourself. i've seen lots of people graduated, who complain about school never taught them when they meet new things in real world. it's bad. figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `obj` directory doesn't exist, so `gcc` cannot write the output file there.

You could create it automatically from the Makefile, but depending on what you want to do, a simple `mkdir obj` might be all you need.

However, it looks like you are running your Makefile from the `src` directory. Chances are you want to run it from your project's root directory and specify `src/` where needed. You'd want to add an `SDIR` variable (or similar) for that; make sure to remove the `../` on `LDIR`, `IDIR` and `ODIR` in that case.

For example, where you currently use `%.c`, use `$(SDIR)/%.c` instead, and move your Makefile appropriately.

Comment: It worked when I created an obj directory within src. However, it's still not working, check the edit I made on the question. Also, it's just a college project and my professor wants the makefile and the code split between src, include and lib.

Comment: Updated to take care of that.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but after I create the SDIR variable, what should I do with it? (There are no straight forward tutorials that teach how to create a makefile, and I'm overburdened with finals and projects, so I really don't have time to surf google after detailed stuff on this.)

Comment: See the example I just added

Comment: Same issue: `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/libcalc.o', needed by 'calc'.  Stop.` Also, I updated the code up there

Comment: Also, I've tried the original tutorial source code with the original makefile and it didn't work, the error is the same: `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/hellofunc.o', needed by 'hellomake'.  Stop.`  (http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

Answer (score 0):

according to your cli command, you are running your makefile under `src/`, which is fine, but gcc won't create missing folder for you. here is the code runs in my linux:

```
$ tree
.
└── test2.c

0 directories, 1 file

$ gcc -c -o obj/test2.o test2.c
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/test2.o: No such file or directory

$ mkdir obj

$ gcc -c -o obj/test2.o test2.c

$ tree
.
├── obj
│   └── test2.o
└── test2.c

1 directory, 2 files
```

Comment: I created an obj directory under src, but it's still not working. The new error is: `make: *** No rule to make target 'bj/libcalc.o', needed by 'calc'.  Stop.`

Comment: @EightbitPoe you had a typo in your makefile. pay attention to the error prompting. you name the folder to be `bj` instead of `obj`. and according to your new makefile up there, you don't have rule to make `libcalc.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Do touch main.o in src/obj that worked for me