# make not working as expected

Tags: c, makefile

I tried to create a *Makefile* to made my work easier but, it seems like I did something wrong.. down below is the project file contents:

## workspace

```
 Project/
         Makefile
             src/
                   main/
                         main.c
                    lib/
                         lib.c
                         lib.h
             bin/
                   main/
                         main.o
                    lib/
                         lib.o
```

this is how my project looks like, and after i run `make`, it's not working as expected i can't figure out what is wrong with my `Makefile`.

```
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:here$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/src/lib/lib.o', needed by `main'.  Stop.
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:here$ ls
bin  Makefile  Makefile~  src
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:here$
```

anyone could take a look and tell me what is the problem, and how to solve it

### Makefile

```
#
CC = gcc
RM = rm
EXEC = main
# #
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = bin
# #
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
SRCDIRS := $(shell find . -name '*.c' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq) 
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
OBJ = # main.o lib.o
DEPS = lib.h
# #
CFLAGS = -I. -Wall -std=c99 -save-temps 
LDFLAGS = #

.PHONY: clean all run remake
all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "Finish."
#
$(EXEC): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(CFLAGS)
#
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
#
run:
    ./$(EXEC)
#
remake: clean all
#
buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)
#
define make-repo
   for dir in $(SRCDIRS); \
   do \
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir; \
   done
endef
#
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up.."
    $(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)` by `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)`?

Comment: Also `OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))` should be `OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
```

with

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
```

Replace

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```

with

```
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```

Replace

```
DEPS = lib.h
```

with

```
DEPS = $(SRCDIR)/lib/lib.h`.
```

At least it works for me.

Edit: fixing the `buildrepo` target

Change `SRCDIRS` definition (dropping the starting "./") and add `OBJDIRS` definition:

```
SRCDIRS := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJDIRS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(SRCDIRS))
```

Now use `OBJDIRS` in target `buildrepo`. Also add `buildrepo` in `.PHONY` list.

```
.PHONY: clean all run remake buildrepo
# ...
define make-repo
    for dir in $(OBJDIRS); \
    do \
      mkdir -p $$dir; \
    done
endef
```

So your full Makefile should be now:

```
#
CC = gcc
RM = rm
EXEC = main
# #
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = bin
# #
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
SRCDIRS := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
OBJDIRS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(SRCDIRS))
OBJ = # main.o lib.o
DEPS = $(SRCDIR)/lib/lib.h
# #
CFLAGS = -I. -Wall -std=c99 -save-temps 
LDFLAGS = #

.PHONY: clean all run remake buildrepo
all: $(EXEC)
    @echo "Finish."
#
$(EXEC): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(CFLAGS)
#
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
#
run:
    ./$(EXEC)
#
remake: clean all
#
buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)
#
define make-repo
    for dir in $(OBJDIRS); \
    do \
      mkdir -p $$dir; \
    done
endef
#
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up.."
    $(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Comment: i still got this error message : `Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create bin/lib/lib.o: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @010010001 That seems to me to be a compiler error, this should mean your makefile problem is solved...

Comment: i did not understand you well, is this normal? or i have to add something else? (thanks by the way)

Comment: @010010001 What is printed before you message error? Isn't there a printed compilation command?

Comment: @010010001 Just found [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657242/makefile-fatal-error-cant-create-obj-calc-o) with my favorite web search engine. (DuckDuckGoing your message error). You just need to create the directories bin/main and bin/lib.

Comment: yes that works just fine! thank bro, you helped a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109351/discussion-between-010010001-and-jdarthenay).