# Automatic directory creation with makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

We are using makefile for our project (at my workplace). I have two copies of the code at the same commit in dir1 and dir2. In dir1, where I wrote the initial makefile and pushed the relevant changes, I am able to build all targets without problem. In the separately cloned dir2, however, make fails, unless I explicitly create the entire output directory structure for the failed target, though it is able to create the output directories for other targets (the last out of 4 targets fails).

I checked these:
[Makefile Fatal error: can't create obj/calc.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657242/makefile-fatal-error-cant-create-obj-calc-o)
and https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2016-06/msg00022.html

Didn't help much.

Any way to fix this inconsistent behavior would be great!!

Details below:

```
$make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

~/dir1 2020-02-14 00:12:40
$cc --version
cc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

While building in dir1:

```
~/dir1 2020-02-13 23:34:05
$ make clean all

~/dir1 2020-02-13 23:34:05
$make clean all
rm -f build/m1/p1/os/p1.o build/m1/p1/t2.o build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o lib/libp1.a lib/libt1.a lib/libp3.a p3_app build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o build/examples/util/util_os.o
cc -c m1/p1/os/p1.c -o build/m1/p1/os/p1.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c m1/p1/t2.c -o build/m1/p1/t2.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p1 module...
ar crv lib/libp1.a build/m1/p1/os/p1.o build/m1/p1/t2.o
a - build/m1/p1/os/p1.o
a - build/m1/p1/t2.o
ranlib lib/libp1.a
cc -c m1/t1/t1_t2.c -o build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c m1/t1/proj_t1.c -o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building t1 module...
ar crv lib/libt1.a build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o
a - build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o
a - build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o
ranlib lib/libt1.a
cc -c m1/p3/proj_p3.c -o build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p3 module...
ar crv lib/libp3.a build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o
a - build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o
ranlib lib/libp3.a
cc -c examples/p3_app/p3_app.c -o build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c examples/util/util_os.c -o build/examples/util/util_os.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p3 app...
cc build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o build/examples/util/util_os.o lib/libp3.a lib/libt1.a lib/libp1.a -lt2-1.0 -lpthread -o p3_app
building all...


~/dir1 2020-02-13 23:34:09
$git log -1
commit 69e17c772231b8dc8 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Author: XXXXXX
Date:   ----------------
```

While building in dir2:

```
~//dir2 2020-02-13 23:34:19
$git log -1
commit 69e17c772231b8dc8 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Author: XXXXXX
Date:   ----------------

~/dir2 2020-02-13 23:34:21
$make clean all
rm -f build/m1/p1/os/p1.o build/m1/p1/t2.o build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o lib/libp1.a lib/libt1.a lib/libp3.a p3_app build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o build/examples/util/util_os.o
cc -c m1/p1/os/p1.c -o build/m1/p1/os/p1.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c m1/p1/t2.c -o build/m1/p1/t2.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p1 module...
ar crv lib/libp1.a build/m1/p1/os/p1.o build/m1/p1/t2.o
a - build/m1/p1/os/p1.o
a - build/m1/p1/t2.o
ranlib lib/libp1.a
cc -c m1/t1/t1_t2.c -o build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c m1/t1/proj_t1.c -o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building t1 module...
ar crv lib/libt1.a build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o
a - build/m1/t1/t1_t2.o
a - build/m1/t1/proj_t1.o
ranlib lib/libt1.a
cc -c m1/p3/proj_p3.c -o build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p3 module...
ar crv lib/libp3.a build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o
a - build/m1/p3/proj_p3.o
ranlib lib/libp3.a
cc -c examples/p3_app/p3_app.c -o build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
cc -c examples/util/util_os.c -o build/examples/util/util_os.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
building p3 app...
cc build/examples/p3_app/p3_app.o build/examples/util/util_os.o lib/libp3.a lib/libt1.a lib/libp1.a -lt2-1.0 -lpthread -o p3_app
cc -c m1/p2/proj_p2_common.c -o build/m1/p2/proj_p2_common.o  <INCLUDES> -fPIC -Wall -std=gnu11 -Werror -Dproj_OS_os -DDEFAULT_t2_PID=0xEC -g -DDEBUG -Dt2_SUPPORT
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/m1/p2/proj_p2_common.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:134: build/m1/p2/proj_p2_common.o] Error 1
```

"build" and "lib" directories are created through `mkdir -p` in both cases. And all the other internal directories are created automatically.

If I manually run `mkdir -p ~/dir2/build/m1/p2/` then `make all` works fine.

PS: I had to replace the actual directory name and file names with dummy names like p1, p2, t1, os and file, as I'm fairly sure that information cannot be put out on a public platform - but because it'is search and replace, I'm sure this closely resembles the output I have.

Comment: I don't see any `mkdir` commands in _either_ output.  And since you've not shown us any part of the makefile which is involved with creating directories, there's little we can do to explain why it's not working.

Comment: I am expecting make to create the required directory structures (which is why no specific mkdirs were used), as it did in the first directory (dir1) and most of dir2, except for some.

Comment: Make will never create any directories at all on its own.  Everything you want to happen you have to do yourself.  If some directories didn't need to be created then they must have already existed, or else there's something in your makefile which created them.

Comment: I expected the same. But it did create subdirs in one case, and didn't in the other, which is what confused me. Anyway, I changed jobs and probably have to close this question as I won't be able to give any more new/debug  info.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it (by _it_ here I mean `gcc`, `ar`, or `make` without any recipe to run mkdir) didn't create directories in any situation.  The other directories must have already existed and you just didn't notice.  Or else there's something in your makefile that is creating most of the directories but not this one for some reason; since we don't have the makefile here there's no way to know that.